# Difference between a LED Backlit and LED HD Display on laptop monitor

Tags: display, laptop-display, led

Is there a difference between a LED Backlit and LED HD  Display on laptop monitor? or are they the same that is good for the eyes

Comment: Sounds like marketing jive to me. Do you have particular model monitors in mind?

Answer (score 2):

There are no actual LED displays available at this time, at least for laptops. Both are going to just be LED backlit.

Comment: Some phones now use OLED technology - now that is tasty.  I want an OLED laptop.